# Two distinct value propositions for two distinct types of users

Tags: layout, information-architecture, users, user-centered-design, homepage

I have two distinct types of users. I would classify them as "beginners" and "advanced" users. I want to describe the value proposition to beginners in one way and to advanced users a different way. There isn't really much overlap.

What are some possible approaches and guidelines for deciding between the approaches?

I see a few possible approaches:

1) Tabs

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv5jUw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

2) Columns (for desktop; I suppose it would become stacked on mobile)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fODl49.png)</sup>

3) Separate pages

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3b4xF.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*The approach described in the third option would work best for your case.*

Please find some remarks about each option below:

1. If there is more than two distinct categories, that are not overlapped at all, i.e. parallel in some hierarchy, the first option with tabs should 2. The second option looks more like a comparison, when information should be considered simultaneously. Taking into account the fact that there is not much overlap, there is little chance that it would be useful.
2. For beginners and advanced categories the third option would work best even if there is an overlap. Such categories can be considered in a single hierarchy and it's good to start with the most basic one, as presented in the screenshot. Besides that, it might be handy to remember if a user requested an advanced version, so he or she doesn't have to do it for each value proposition, though an option to get back to a basic view should be provided as well in case a user change one's mind.